# Unflash a message with Nitrogen

Tags: erlang, nitrogen

I have a login page for my Nitrogen based web app. If user authentication fails I wf:flash a message to the user to let them know. However if the user continues to supply bad credentials these flash message keep building up. Is there a way to first clear the flashed messages before posting a new one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to remove the original flash message by calling:

```
 wf:update(page__flash, [])
```

before updating with the new message (via `wf:flash(Message)`). `page__flash` is the id of the flash container div, and I just set it's content to be empty.

Answer (score 2):

the notify element here: http://github.com/zaphar/nitrogen-elements/tree/master/src/element_notify/

Is an expanded flash that allows you to have set a timed fade away for the flash message and a few other useful options. It might be what you are looking for.